# Downside of setting clear_devices=true when saving or loading graph in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

There are a number of methods in Tensorflow that take a `clear_devices` devices. For example `session_bundle.exporter.Exporter:init`, `import_meta_graph`, `export_meta_graph` and python.training.saver.Saver.export_meta_graph`. The docs state:

> ```
>  clear_devices: Whether or not to clear the device field for an `Operation`
>     or `Tensor` during export.
> ```

But don't really clarify what are the implications of stripping that info off.

Answer (score 1):

Stripping device information from the graph means that, without new device placement directives being added, ops will be placed [per defaults](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu). This may be useful if the exported/imported graph will be executed in a different setup, or if the data fed to it will be different (e.g. serving with a small batch size on the CPU after training on a GPU).